# Converting Dataset[Array[String]] to Dataset[MyCaseClass]

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am working with a csv file like below

```
"age;""job"";""marital"""
"58;""management"";""married"""
"44;""technician"";""single"""
```

Because of the extra quotes, spark.read.csv does not give clean columns.
So I thought of using spark.read.textFile which gives Dataset[String]. I use below code to remove the quotes and split them.

```
case class MyCaseClass(age: String, job: String, marital: String)
val inputDS = spark.read.textFile(inpPath)
val cleanDS = inputDS.map(_.replaceAll(""""""", "").split(";"))
val seperatedDS = cleanDS.as[MyCaseClass] //fails
```

Is there a way to achieve this sort of Dataset convertion or a better way to split out into multiple columns?
For now I am using RDD to get the job done, but would like to know Dataset/Dataframe way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a record of `MyCaseClass` from each split line so that you have `RDD[MyCaseClass]`, then you can directly convert it to data frame:

```
val cleanDS = inputDS.map(line => {
  val fields = line.replaceAll("\"", "").split(";")
  MyCaseClass(fields(0), fields(1), fields(2))
})

cleanDS
// res37: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[MyCaseClass] = [age: string, job: string ... 1 more field]

cleanDS.toDF.show
+---+----------+-------+
|age|       job|marital|

+---+----------+-------+
|age|       job|marital|
| 58|management|married|
| 44|technician| single|
+---+----------+-------+
```